# Collaboration tool to review/add/delete a large amount of box polygons on a map

Tags: qgis, vector

I have a large amount (more than 30k) of simple polygons (i.e. boxes) and at the moment I am using QGIS to review (add/remove) them on map.

Those polygons are vector features extracted from various aerial images, therefore I also need to display different base map layers to assist the review workflow.

Is there any collaboration map tool where I can upload the data so that I could let multiple people to review the data on map collaboratively?

The data can be viewed publicly.
The review process can be none real-time (e.g. submit for consensus).

Comment: Using QGIS server would be an option?

Comment: I think we need some more details. Do the data need to be private, so that people need a password to access it? Do you want to divide the 30k polygons between the users equally? Or have a queue that feeds the next one to the next user who asks for one? Do you want each one reviewed more than once to get a consensus? Solutions could be as simple as "put the data into PostGIS" or as complex as "write a geoDjango web app"...

Comment: @Spacedman "write a geoDjango web app" would be my last choice but it seems there is no much choice for me..

Comment: Depends on the skillset of your reviewers. You could say "hey team, connect to this PostGIS table [details] in QGIS or (any other GIS)and select all with `review="notdone"`, then set to "accept" or "reject" and get another one. Could possibly even do it with a Python+Flask or Dash or something if Django too heavy.